# What type of indexing is needed for fields having numbers in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

I am working on mongodb where i need to apply indexing to several keys for better search efficiency. I am confused between text indexing. The text indexing i can apply for text based searh but for fields like mobile numbers, are stored as integers and not string. What kind of indexing is to be added for fields like this?

Comment: I think you are actually asking the wrong question, if any question needs to be asked at all. This really seems to be more about the sort of data you need to store and what your actual search requirements are. It's better to just explain what you need to do than get lost in discussion of things you clearly are not understanding yet. So talking about indexes is not really going to help here, I don't think. There are only effectively "three" types, being either regular B-Tree, "text" or "geospatial". Hashed indexes not withstanding, nor differences in storage engine processing.

Comment: I know indexing a little bit in terms of MSSQL database but haven't understood of how it works in terms of NOSQL database. that too for particular key based search.

Comment: Like I said, it's really unclear what you are actually asking for here, and it probably would be better if you just asked about what you actually need to do rather than asking an abstract question. Abstract questions rarely give you information you can really use to solve problems, and even more rarely are useful as a reference to anyone else. If your scenario is actually about *"searching for phone numbers"*, then just directly ask that question and present cases. It's better to be direct rather than *"beating around the bush"*. If you don't ask clearly you get the wrong answer.